# How to set embedded controller view of a UITabBarController to be visible below its uitabbar?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a subclass of a UITabBarController. I add many controllers with:

```
self.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [QZFirstViewController new],
                        [QZSecondViewController new],
                        [QZThirdViewController new]
                        nil];
```

Each of these controllers displays one table view on all their view (like a UITableViewController). How can I set these embedded controllers to make their contents visible below the UITabBar?

Comment: Do you want to hide TabBar ?

Comment: No, I just want to have the tabbar above and translucent the bottom of the controller views